# Adding ScrollOut animation to headings using CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/YOPqLb) script uses SCSS to acheive animation to headings during scrolling of the webpage.

I converted it to CSS format and it does not seems to be working when added to a website - [W3Spaces Page Output](https://roughnote.w3spaces.com/heading-animation.html). Is it possible to get the effect with CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style>
h1.splitting {
  color: #84a8ff;
}
h1.splitting .char {
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.3, 1), opacity 0.3s linear;
  transition-delay: calc(20ms * var(--char-index));
}
h1.splitting[data-scroll="out"] .char {
  opacity: 0.1;
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
Splitting();
ScrollOut({
   targets: 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
});
</script>
</head>
<div class="page">

  <h1 data-splitting>ScrollOut + Splitting.js</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent bibendum, lorem vel tincidunt imperdiet, nibh elit laoreet felis, a bibendum nisl tortor non orci. Donec pretium fermentum felis, quis aliquet est rutrum ut. Integer quis massa ut lacus viverra pharetra in eu lacus. Aliquam tempus odio adipiscing diam pellentesque rhoncus. Curabitur a bibendum est. Mauris vehicula cursus risus id luctus. Curabitur accumsan venenatis nibh, non egestas ipsum vulputate ac. Vivamus consectetur dolor sit amet enim aliquet eu scelerisque ipsum hendrerit. Donec lobortis suscipit vestibulum. Nullam luctus pellentesque risus in ullamcorper. Nam neque nunc, mattis vitae ornare ut, feugiat a erat. Ut tempus iaculis augue vel pellentesque.</p>

  <h1 data-splitting>Triggering Splitting Animations on Scroll</h1>

  <p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu dolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim. Cras in eros id tortor fringilla ultricies. Mauris faucibus ullamcorper velit, pulvinar varius odio eleifend eu. Quisque id odio metus. Morbi adipiscing ultricies posuere. Pellentesque elementum porttitor eros in molestie. Maecenas ut leo quis nisi tempor tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Donec nunc ligula, vulputate quis mollis eu, interdum quis libero. Donec nulla ante, facilisis sit amet vulputate at, tincidunt a velit. Maecenas vestibulum, nulla sed tincidunt viverra, lorem turpis aliquam urna, ut pretium orci purus consequat augue. Etiam a enim orci, vitae pulvinar odio. In elit urna, tincidunt a pellentesque et, scelerisque at nibh. Sed nec est sapien. Aliquam ullamcorper eros eu quam ultrices vel faucibus eros interdum. Etiam mattis eleifend sapien, eu iaculis massa feugiat sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus facilisis ultricies eros, a pretium purus mollis id. Sed dapibus elit ut neque rutrum dignissim. Nulla eros nisl, venenatis quis rhoncus sit amet, molestie nec nisl. Pellentesque vel neque sapien, et sagittis nulla.</p>

  <h1 data-splitting>Add a <code>transition</code> to your splits (<code>.char</code> for example)</h1>

  <p>Aliquam eu iaculis mauris. Etiam arcu lectus, imperdiet sit amet volutpat vitae, commodo sed nibh. Fusce faucibus tempor cursus. Donec ut ligula tortor. Maecenas malesuada, diam vitae pharetra dictum, erat ante iaculis risus, sed sollicitudin nisl nisl vel metus. Nulla libero augue, convallis nec luctus id, iaculis nec urna. Cras vitae mi ut augue ultricies tempus.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum euismod vehicula sollicitudin. Duis nibh justo, rhoncus ac ullamcorper nec, rutrum sit amet leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum varius posuere nisi sed aliquet. Etiam dolor nisi, placerat vel congue tempus, posuere sed erat. Phasellus turpis eros, molestie sed consequat in, pretium at erat. In sed faucibus metus. Vestibulum fermentum libero nec eros fermentum dapibus. Duis nec libero eros. Pellentesque magna ligula, sagittis dictum fringilla at, posuere porttitor sem. Donec aliquam, ipsum quis pulvinar dapibus, augue sem viverra sapien, nec tempus odio nulla ac metus. Nunc ut augue mi, nec consequat urna.</p>

  <h1 data-splitting>Target <code>[data-scroll="out"]</code> for the default state</h1>


  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent bibendum, lorem vel tincidunt imperdiet, nibh elit laoreet felis, a bibendum nisl tortor non orci. Donec pretium fermentum felis, quis aliquet est rutrum ut. Integer quis massa ut lacus viverra pharetra in eu lacus. Aliquam tempus odio adipiscing diam pellentesque rhoncus. Curabitur a bibendum est. Mauris vehicula cursus risus id luctus. Curabitur accumsan venenatis nibh, non egestas ipsum vulputate ac. Vivamus consectetur dolor sit amet enim aliquet eu scelerisque ipsum hendrerit. Donec lobortis suscipit vestibulum. Nullam luctus pellentesque risus in ullamcorper. Nam neque nunc, mattis vitae ornare ut, feugiat a erat. Ut tempus iaculis augue vel pellentesque.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum nunc massa, gravida quis porta nec, feugiat id metus. Nunc ac arcu dolor, quis vestibulum leo. Cras viverra mollis ipsum, non rhoncus lectus aliquam et. Morbi faucibus purus sit amet lacus aliquet elementum. Donec sit amet posuere enim. Cras in eros id tortor fringilla ultricies. Mauris faucibus ullamcorper velit, pulvinar varius odio eleifend eu. Quisque id odio metus. Morbi adipiscing ultricies posuere. Pellentesque elementum porttitor eros in molestie. Maecenas ut leo quis nisi tempor tincidunt.</p>


  <h1 data-splitting>That's about it!</h1>

  <p>Donec nunc ligula, vulputate quis mollis eu, interdum quis libero. Donec nulla ante, facilisis sit amet vulputate at, tincidunt a velit. Maecenas vestibulum, nulla sed tincidunt viverra, lorem turpis aliquam urna, ut pretium orci purus consequat augue. Etiam a enim orci, vitae pulvinar odio. In elit urna, tincidunt a pellentesque et, scelerisque at nibh. Sed nec est sapien. Aliquam ullamcorper eros eu quam ultrices vel faucibus eros interdum. Etiam mattis eleifend sapien, eu iaculis massa feugiat sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus facilisis ultricies eros, a pretium purus mollis id. Sed dapibus elit ut neque rutrum dignissim. Nulla eros nisl, venenatis quis rhoncus sit amet, molestie nec nisl. Pellentesque vel neque sapien, et sagittis nulla.</p>

  <p>Aliquam eu iaculis mauris. Etiam arcu lectus, imperdiet sit amet volutpat vitae, commodo sed nibh. Fusce faucibus tempor cursus. Donec ut ligula tortor. Maecenas malesuada, diam vitae pharetra dictum, erat ante iaculis risus, sed sollicitudin nisl nisl vel metus. Nulla libero augue, convallis nec luctus id, iaculis nec urna. Cras vitae mi ut augue ultricies tempus.</p>



  <h1 data-splitting>For real. It's easy!</h1>

  <p>Vestibulum euismod vehicula sollicitudin. Duis nibh justo, rhoncus ac ullamcorper nec, rutrum sit amet leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum varius posuere nisi sed aliquet. Etiam dolor nisi, placerat vel congue tempus, posuere sed erat. Phasellus turpis eros, molestie sed consequat in, pretium at erat. In sed faucibus metus. Vestibulum fermentum libero nec eros fermentum dapibus. Duis nec libero eros. Pellentesque magna ligula, sagittis dictum fringilla at, posuere porttitor sem. Donec aliquam, ipsum quis pulvinar dapibus, augue sem viverra sapien, nec tempus odio nulla ac metus. Nunc ut augue mi, nec consequat urna.</p>
</div>
<script>
Splitting();
ScrollOut({
   targets: 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I have changed the JS code to just target all the headings:

```
ScrollOut({
   targets: 'h1,h2,h3,h4'
});
```

The SCSS also converted into CSS.

But the code is not working.

Comment: Have you included the third party CDN for the library or installed to your server with NPM?

Comment: No, I haven't included any third party CDN. How to do it?

Comment: Check out this page my friend... https://splitting.js.org/guide.html#using-a-cdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed external CSS and Js library call,

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.css' type='text/css' />
<style>
    h1.splitting {
        color: #84a8ff;
    }
    h1.splitting .char {
        transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.3, 1), opacity 0.3s linear;
        transition-delay: calc( 20ms * var(--char-index) );
    }
    h1.splitting[data-scroll=out] .char {
        opacity: 0.1;
        transform: translateY(0.25em);
    }
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.js"></script>
```

Then, use it's method/options

```
<script>
    Splitting();
    ScrollOut({
        targets: '[data-splitting]'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add these resources for it to work the way you want

EXTERNAL CSS

[css resource](https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.css)

EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT

[js resource#1](https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.js)

[js resource#2](https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.js)